# CPU Freq Indicator only runs if I leave the terminal open

Tags: indicator, applet, mint

I installed `indicator-cpufreq` and it is in my startup applications.

My problem is it only will start if I start it in a terminal and leave the terminal open. It doesn't start when logging on and won't stay open after I close the terminal.

How can I get it to actually start with the computer?

Comment: There is a system monitor built in ubuntu 12.04 and above.Use that.Go to Dash->System Monitor

Comment: It's hard to figure out what problem it is but you can try `setsid indicator-cpufreq` instead of leaving terminal open. **setsid** will run it on background and you can close terminal.

Comment: The functionality is supposed to start on boot. It is listed in Startup Applications but does not start. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this needs to be in startup applications twice but the startup applet removes duplicate values from the list, adding "setsid indicator-cpufreq" with a delay of 20 and "indicator-cpufreq" with a delay of 5 appears to solve the issue on my Mint system.